# How to add customized cell in tableview when user selects cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to add my customized tableviewcell in my tableview when user selects a cell I have some buttons on that customized cell and want to give user option as soon he selects a cell.

Any suggestions and guidance to move on from here?

Comment: Are you pushing a new view or do you want cells to slide in to the current tableview?

Comment: I can go either way..just need some direction of how to approach

Answer (score 0):

you have to use customize cell when cell is created and change the image of the cell when it will selected.

Answer (score 0):

Create two custom cells, one for the normal rows and other for the required row. When the user touches a particular cell, you can record it's indexPath and reload the tableView. When the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called the second time after tableView reload, you can identify the row with the flag set earlier. You can then create a new cell for it.